# Layout Building - Div elements not aligining

Tags: html, css

Im trying to build a layout...The first 3 containers are displaying as expected..
I want the container 4 to be displayed along side of container1,container2,container

RequirementL
Container 4 should be displayed next to (Container1 + 2 + 3)

fiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/prem1980/39rJd/1/

html

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div id="container1">
        container-1
    </div>
    <div id="container2">
    </div>
    <div id="container3">
    </div>
    <div id="container4">
        container 4
    </div>

</div>
```

css

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    /*background-color:#AFEEEE;*/
    background-color:grey;
}

#main-container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;

    /*margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;    */
}

#container1 {
    height:60%;
    width:30%;
    margin:10px 10px;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

#container2 {
    height:20%;
    width:30%;
    margin:10px 10px;
    background-color:yellow;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

#container3 {
    height:20%;
    width:30%;
    margin:10px 10px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

#container4 {
    height:100%;
    width:30%;
    margin:10px 10px;
    background-color:orange;
    float:left;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create two columns, right? The top op `#container-4` should be aligned with the top of `#container-1`.

To do that you'll need to create a wrapper div around `#container-1`, `#container-2` and `#container-3`. Then you can also drop the floats, clears and width's of those three divs.

HTML

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div id="container123">
        <div id="container1">
            container-1
        </div>
        <div id="container2">
            container-2
        </div>
        <div id="container3">
            container-3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container4">
        container 4
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container123 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
#container1 {
    height:60%;
    margin:10px 0;
    background-color:green;
}
#container2 {
    height:20%;
    margin:10px 0;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#container3 {
    height:20%;
    margin:10px 0;
    background-color:red;
}
#container4 {
    height:100%;
    width:30%;
    margin:10px 10px;
    background-color:orange;
    float: left;
}
```

Check the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/39rJd/5/)

[EDIT]
If you don't need `#main-container`, you could delete it, check [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39rJd/6/).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `clear:both` on container 4:

```
#container4 {
    height:100%;
    width:30%;
    margin:10px 10px;
    background-color:orange;
    float:left;
    clear:both;

}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39rJd/2/)

Comment: I need to rephrase when I mean alongside..its sidewards ..ie; container 4 should be displayed next to (Container1 + 2 + 3)

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear:both` to `.container4`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39rJd/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your #container4:

```
position:absolute;
top:8px;
left:35%;
```